# Wordpress, background image not showing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a little experience with CSS and HTML, but currently working on a website for a friend of mine. I'm using Wordpress and he wants a picture in the header and thats where I am currently stuck.

I read that it is a good practice to set the image as the background image inside a `div` tag. My problem is that the image is not showing, so I am assuming that I have an error with the path I am using. When inserting a picture that is online, it works perfectly.

Here's my div inside the header.php file:

```
<div id="bottom-header-section"></div>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```
#bottom-header-section {    
    background-image: url('\images\title.jpg');
    height: 95px;
    width: 613px;
    margin: inherit;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 35%;
    background-position: right bottom; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If I delete the background-image completely, I can see that the size of the `div` gets smaller. I tried every different path that came to my mind..

Also, what is the best way to make the image responsive?

Comment: is this live somewhere?

Comment: No not yet, only working locally so far

Comment: Can you try by reversing the slashes in the background image url

Comment: Yep, I just tried /images/title.jpg and "/images/title.jpg" and '/images/title.jpg'

Comment: background: url('../images/title.jpg'); , if its not at the root.

Comment: Thanks, madhuri, I tried that. But it seems that something "invisible" is inserted

Comment: Can you check if the image is loaded, by going to the inspector , and in Sources tab, and if you see the image then it is probably the path referenced or the CSS.

Comment: And also give background-size:cover ;

Comment: Thanks, I went to the inspector and checked the images folder there. It doesnt show my jpg.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180682/discussion-between-constantin-m-and-madhuri-kulkarni).

Answer (score 0):

Try using '../images/title.jpg' - this should work

Comment: thanks, I tried that, but it is not working. Does restarting the local http or mysql server help?

Comment: I would suggest trying: 

background-image: url('../themes/your-theme/images/title.jpg')

or


background-image: url('/themes/your-theme/images/title.jpg')

hopefully this works

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your image and stylesheet are located within the file tree.

This is how the path should read:

```
#bottom-header-section { 
    background-image: url('../images/title.jpg');
}
```

The tree should something like this:

`wp-content
    - themes
      - your-theme 
         - images
             - title.jpg
         - css
             - style.css`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My absolute path of the images folder is C:\xampp\htdocs\wertesystem\wp-content\themes\spacious\image. So the path for the css should be /images/title.jpg right?

Comment: It should include ".../" beforehand as it needs to know to come out of the CSS folder first and THEN go into the images folder.

Comment: What is your filename? Stab in the dark, but have you got any whitespace or any invalid characters in the filename. Also, have you tried testing this div with an external image to see if it actually shows up? Use "http://placekitten.com/200/300" for quick testing

Comment: The filename is title.jpg, I just checked it and renamed it again. Still doesnt work. Yes, external pictures work I have also tried that as stated earlier. I was also able to add the picture to the div as an image earlier by using html..

Comment: Ok I just browsed the media files and now using this path: http://localhost/wertesystem/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/title.jpg and it works perfectly.... Is it a problem to use this path? I will probably have to change it going when going online right?

Comment: Can I add another question to this question? So I want the image in the bottom right of the header. Therer for I aligned it by using the margin. This doesnt make it responsive... How can I change the code so the div is still in the bottom right of the header but changes size when changing the size of the browser window?

Comment: It may be best to position the header relative and setting the image absolute. You want to position is bottom: 0 and right: 0. You may need to set a percentage on the image to make that resize as the window gets smaller.